# Finding composite matrices after linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vectors, linear-transformations

"Let T1 be the reflection about the line -6x-5y = 0 and T2 be the reflection about the line 4x-y = 0 in the euclidean plane.

a) i) What is the standard matrix of T1∘T2?

ii) Thus, by how many radians is the resulting counterclockwise rotation about the origin?

b) i) What is the standard matrix of T2∘T1?

ii) Thus, by how many radians is the resulting counterclockwise rotation about the origin?"

I have managed to solve for the standard matrices for each of T1 and T2, but I am not sure how to find the composites required. Do I multiply them together according to the order written above or is there another way?

I am also not sure how to find the amount of radians. Is there a formula for that or another way?

Comment: When composing matrices I write them as $A(Bu)$ and $B(Au)$ so I can see clearly which order the matrix operations will will act on the vector $u$. Once that's clear it's just matrix multiplication and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats right. Just multiply the matrices.  In a rotation by angle $A$ the first entry will be cos(A). Use this fact the other way. SO the angle would be cosine inverse of the entry at $(1,1)$.